# Flex - Align Elements Horizontally In The Remaining Space

Tags: css, flexbox

Im learning Flex as I go along. I think the code will do a better job of explaing the issue.

https://codepen.io/kayote/pen/PzdXLQ

I have two elements ( `C`, `=` ) in a container which need to be moved to the empty space alongside the numbers container. I think flex can do this, can it?

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself.

Comment: Also an image of what this is **suppposed** to look like.

Comment: You'll need to wrap `div.numberParent` and `div.assignParent` in common container and then it's as straightforward as setting `display: flex` on this outer element

Comment: I have seen this problem before. flexbox does not work with 2 or more column heights. Or not yet anyway. You will need a separate area for them and float them to the right

Comment: @robjez that did it. Thank you, would you please post the answer so that it can be accepted. The result is viewable in the above codepen.

Comment: @Kayote - sure, answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

1. Change the `flex-direction` property of the `.btnContainer` element to `row`.
2. Change the `justify-content` property of the `.btnContainer` element to `flex-start`.
3. Reduce the `width` of the `.numberParent` element by `12px`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
  font-family: 'Reem Kufi', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #c1c1c1;
}
#calcParent {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 12px auto;
  border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#display {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #999;
  height: 66px;
  text-align: : right;
  border-color: #3a3a3a;
  border-width: 2px 2px 4px;
  border-style: solid;
}
#curVal {
  font-size: 33px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 66px;
  padding: 0 9px;
}
#totalVal {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 6px;
  color: #333;
}
.btnContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}
.numberParent {
  width: calc(80% - 12px);
}
.assignParent {
  width: 20%;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align:center;
}
.btnDblHor {
  width: 133px;
  height: 60px;
}
.btnDblVer {
  height: 133px;
  width: 60px;
  line-height: 133px;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #cc9933;
}
```

```html
<div id="calcParent">
  <div id="display">
    <div id="curVal"></div>
    <div id="totalVal"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="btnContainer">
    <div class="operatorParent">
      <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">/</div>
      <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">x</div>
      <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">-</div>
      <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="numberParent">
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">9</div>
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">8</div>
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">7</div>
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">6</div>
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">5</div>
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">4</div>
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">3</div>
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">2</div>
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">1</div>
      <div class="btn btnDblHor" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">0</div>
      <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="assignParent">
      <div class="btn btnDblVer" onClick="clearDisplay()">C</div>
      <div class="btn btnDblVer" onClick="">=</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution to your problem would be to wrap `div.numberParent` and `div.assignParent` in common container and then it's as straightforward as setting `display: flex` on this outer element. This way you end up having 2 elements on the DOM tree, which you can "spread" horizontally with `flex`, as so:

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
  font-family: 'Reem Kufi', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #c1c1c1;
}
#calcParent {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 440px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 12px auto;
  border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#display {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #999;
  height: 66px;
  text-align: : right;
  border-color: #3a3a3a;
  border-width: 2px 2px 4px;
  border-style: solid;
}
#curVal {
  font-size: 33px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 66px;
  padding: 0 9px;
}
#totalVal {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 6px;
  color: #333;
}
.btnContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}
.operatorParent {} .numberParent {
  width: 80%;
}
.assignParent {
  width: 20%;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.btnDblHor {
  width: 133px;
  height: 60px;
}
.btnDblVer {
  height: 133px;
  width: 60px;
  line-height: 133px;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #cc9933;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="calcParent">
  <div id="display">
    <div id="curVal"></div>
    <div id="totalVal"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="btnContainer">
    <div class="operatorParent">
      <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">/</div>
      <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">x</div>
      <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">-</div>
      <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="numberParent">
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">9</div>
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">8</div>
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">7</div>
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">6</div>
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">5</div>
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">4</div>
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">3</div>
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">2</div>
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">1</div>
        <div class="btn btnDblHor" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">0</div>
        <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="assignParent">
        <div class="btn btnDblVer" onClick="clearDisplay()">C</div>
        <div class="btn btnDblVer" onClick="">=</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution no.2 (no extra div, with relative sizing)**

```js
const curVal = document.getElementById( "curVal" );
const totalVal = document.getElementById( "totalVal" );
let result = 0,
  curTotalArr = [],
  curValArr = [  ];

const updateCurVal = function( e ){
 var str = curValArr.join( "" );
 console.log( str );
 if( curValArr.join( "" ).match( /([-+\/x])/g )){
  curTotalArr.push( curValArr );
  totalVal.textContent = mergeArr();  
  console.log( "curTotalArr", curTotalArr );
  curValArr = [  ];
 }
 console.log( "curTotalArr is...", curTotalArr );
 let val = e.target.textContent;
 console.log( val );
 if( val == "." && curValArr.indexOf( "." ) > 0 ){
  return false;
 }
 curValArr.push( val );
 console.log( curValArr );
 curVal.textContent = curValArr.join( "" );
}

const mergeArr = function(){
 let mergeArr1 = [];
 let merger = curTotalArr.map( function( val ){
  mergeArr1.push( val.join("")); 
 });
 console.log( merger );
 return mergeArr1.join( "" );
}

const addOperator = function( e ){
 if( curValArr.join("").match( /([0-9])/g )){
  curTotalArr.push( curValArr );
  totalVal.textContent = mergeArr();  
 }
 let val = e.target.textContent;
 console.log( val );
 curValArr = [ val ];
 curVal.textContent = curValArr.join( "" );
 let arrLength = curTotalArr.length;
 console.log( arrLength );
}

const clearDisplay = function(){
 curTotalArr = [];
 curValArr = [  ];
 curVal.textContent = curValArr.join( "" );
 totalVal.textContent = curTotalArr.join( "" );
}

const displayResult = function(){
 
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #444;
 font-family: 'Reem Kufi', sans-serif;
 font-size : 10px;
 color : #000;
 text-shadow : 0 0 1px #c1c1c1;
}

#calcParent {
 display : block;
 width : 300px;
 height : 440px;
 background-color : white;
 margin : 12px auto;
 border : 3px solid #1a1a1a;
 border-radius : 3px;
}
#display {
 display : block;
 position: relative;
 width : 100%;
 background-color : #999;
 height : 66px;
 text-align: : right;
 border-color : #3a3a3a;
 border-width : 2px 2px 4px;
 border-style : solid;
}
#curVal {
 font-size : 33px;
 text-align : right;
 line-height : 66px;
 padding : 0 9px;
}
#totalVal {
 font-size : 18px;
 text-align: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left : 6px;
 color : #333;
}
.btnContainer {
 display : flex;
 flex-direction : row;
 flex-wrap : wrap;
 justify-content : flex-end;
 align-items : space-between;
 align-content : space-between;
}
.operatorParent {
 width:100%;
}
.numberParent {
 width : 75%;
}
.assignParent {
 width: 25%;
}
.btn {
 display : inline-block;
 width : 58px;
 height : 60px;
 font-size : 30px;
 line-height : 40px;
 background-color : gold;
 margin : 6px;
 border : 1px solid black;
 border-radius : 3px;
}
.btnDblHor {
 width : 133px;
 height : 60px;
}
.btnDblVer {
 height : 133px;
 width: 60px;
 line-height : 133px;
}

.btn:hover {
 background-color : yellow;
 color : black;
 border : 1px solid #cc9933;
}
```

```html
<div id="calcParent">
 <div id="display">
  <div id="curVal"></div>
  <div id="totalVal"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="btnContainer">
  <div class="operatorParent">
   <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">/</div>
   <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">x</div>
   <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">-</div>
   <div class="btn" onclick="addOperator( event )">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="numberParent">
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">9</div>
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">8</div>
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">7</div>
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">6</div>
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">5</div>
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">4</div>
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">3</div>
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">2</div>
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">1</div>
   <div class="btn btnDblHor" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">0</div>
   <div class="btn" onClick="updateCurVal(event)">.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="assignParent">
   <div class="btn btnDblVer" onClick="clearDisplay()">C</div>
   <div class="btn btnDblVer" onClick="">=</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Where you'll need to set `flex-direction` as in previous solution to `.row`, and then set the `widths` of containers accordingly to `100%` per 1st row of buttons, then `75%` and `25%` on 2nd and 3rd elements: `.numberParent` and `.assignParent` accordingly (since 3 btns out of 4 gives you 75% of width you want them to occupy).

Comment: thanks robjez, shaggy's solution is a bit better as it doesnt require an additional div. However, both are useful so both have been voted up. Shaggy's answer has been accepted as it meets the requirement without further amendment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-wrap: wrap` to your advantage here, if you give each `div` a correctly proportioned `flex-basis`.

Without touching the markup, the flexbox styles you will need are:

```
.btnContainer,
.operatorParent,
.number-assign,
.numberParent,
.assignParent {
display : flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.btnContainer {
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.operatorParent {
flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.numberParent {
flex: 1 0 75%;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.assignParent {
flex: 1 0 25%;
flex-direction : column;
}
```

**Complete Example:**

```css
body {
 background-color: #444;
 font-family: 'Reem Kufi', sans-serif;
 font-size : 10px;
 color : #000;
 text-shadow : 0 0 1px #c1c1c1;
}

#calcParent {
 display : block;
 width : 300px;
 height : 440px;
 background-color : white;
 margin : 12px auto;
 border : 3px solid #1a1a1a;
 border-radius : 3px;
}
#display {
 display : block;
 position: relative;
 width : 100%;
 background-color : #999;
 height : 66px;
 text-align: : right;
 border-color : #3a3a3a;
 border-width : 2px 2px 4px;
 border-style : solid;
}
#curVal {
 font-size : 33px;
 text-align : right;
 line-height : 66px;
 padding : 0 9px;
}
#totalVal {
 font-size : 18px;
 text-align: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left : 6px;
 color : #333;
}

.btn {
 width : 60px;
 height : 60px;
 font-size : 30px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height : 40px;
 background-color : gold;
 margin : 6px;
 border : 1px solid black;
 border-radius : 3px;
}

.btnDblHor {
 width : 133px;
 height : 60px;
}
.btnDblVer {
 height : 133px;
 width: 60px;
 line-height : 133px;
}

.btn:hover {
 background-color : yellow;
 color : black;
 border : 1px solid #cc9933;
}


.btnContainer,
.operatorParent,
.number-assign,
.numberParent,
.assignParent {
display : flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.btnContainer {
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.operatorParent {
flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.numberParent {
flex: 1 0 75%;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.assignParent {
flex: 1 0 25%;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="calcParent">
<div id="display">
<div id="curVal"></div>
<div id="totalVal"></div>
</div>

<div class="btnContainer">

<div class="operatorParent">
<div class="btn">/</div>
<div class="btn">x</div>
<div class="btn">-</div>
<div class="btn">+</div>
</div>

<div class="numberParent">
<div class="btn">9</div>
<div class="btn">8</div>
<div class="btn">7</div>
<div class="btn">6</div>
<div class="btn">5</div>
<div class="btn">4</div>
<div class="btn">3</div>
<div class="btn">2</div>
<div class="btn">1</div>
<div class="btn btnDblHor">0</div>
<div class="btn">.</div>
</div>

<div class="assignParent">
<div class="btn btnDblVer">C</div>
<div class="btn btnDblVer">=</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Havent tested this yet but sounds interesting, upvoted with thanks.